# How to effectively relay information back from a class to the main program?

Tags: c#, class, monogame

I have a program, which has a number of classes, to which I relay input information; to determine which class I should relay the input to, I have a variable that holds the current class "in focus", if you will.

The below is a pseudocode to demonstrate:

```
class Class1 ...
class Class2 ...

Class1 class1 = new Class1;
Class2 class2 = new Class2;

string currentClass = "class1";

KeyboardState kbstate = Keyboard.State();

switch (currentClass)
{
    case "class1":
        class1.HandleInput(kbstate);
    case "class2":
        class2.HandleInput(kbstate);
}
```

I want to have the class hold a state, e.g. Class1 to have a property *isActive*, which, if false, will cause the active class to shift to another class (say, Class2) - that is to say, the variable `currentClass` in the main program will change to *class2*, so input will then be redirected to this class.

I could do this by having another if statement (in the main program), checking the contents of the *isActive* in each class and changing if the class is currently inactive, but since I want to do on a game (w/ monogame), this code would execute 60 times a second, which is quite a waste.

The real life application of this would be say, to change from the StartMenu class handling input to the MainGame class handling input, once the Start Game button is clicked on the main menu.

Does anyone have a way to implement this without this recurrent checking for changes in variables like this?

I am also pretty sure this is bad code design, but I don't know a better way, so if anyone can suggest a better way it would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes are similar, you can look into interfaces or even inheritance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/interfaces

Basically, you don't need to save current class in a string.

```
interface IGameClass
{
    void HandleInput();
}

class Class1: IGameClass ...
class Class2: IGameClass ...

KeyboardState kbstate = Keyboard.State();

Class1 class1 = new Class1;
Class2 class2 = new Class2;

IGameClass CurrentClass = class1; // Set this instead of string

CurrentClass.HandleInput(kbstate);
```

About your recurrent bool checking, you can use property with backing field and change current class when setting the isactive bool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties

```
class Class1
{
    int _isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isActive;
        }
        set
        {
            this._number = value;
            
            // Sample logic
            if(value)
            {   
                CurrentClass = class1;
            }
            else 
            {
                CurrentClass = class2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know about interfaces. In the code you gave for the recurrent bool check bit, CurrentClass/class1/class2 are all in Class1, so they are not be able to accessed in that context since they were defined in main, meaning that it couldn't change the CurrentClass. How would I get around that?

Comment: You can make those fields static. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members